# How to add hardcodded block to content of a CMS block or page in magento backend

Tags: magento2

I have a block in footer which is hardcoded, is there a way to put in cms contents?
enabling template path hints show it template to be

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml
```

And it block is showing to be

```
Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Subscribe
```

I want to insert it anywhere in CMS pages or block content. I tried this code

```
{{block class="Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Block\Subscribe"  template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

In my blogpost content section but in fornt end show nothing.

[image: This is template]

[image: This is frontend]

[image: This is block]

Here is the content of phtml file **Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe $block */

?>
<div class="block newsletter">
    <div class="title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Newsletter')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe"
            novalidate
            action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormActionUrl()) ?>"
            method="post"
            data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
            id="newsletter-validate-detail">
            <div class="field newsletter">
                <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter"
                                placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enter your email address')) ?>"
                                data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subscribe')) ?>" type="submit">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Join')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subscribe-modal-popup">
    <div class="title-message">Oops, something has gone wrong </div>
    <div class="success-message"></div>
    <div class="success-error"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('newsletter-message-error')->toHtml(); ?></div>
</div>
<!-- <script>
 require(['jquery'],function($){
 var form = $('#newsletter-validate-detail');
 form.submit(function(e) {
   if(form.validation('isValid')){
        $('.subscribe-modal-popup').removeClass('error');
        var serializedForm = form.serialize();
        var email = $("#newsletter").val();
        var url = form.attr('action');
        // console.log(email+' - '+url);
        // console.log(serializedForm);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: serializedForm,
            showLoader: true, //use for display loader 
            success: function (response){
                $('.subscribe-modal-popup').modal('openModal');
                // console.log(response);
                if (!response.error) {
                    $('.subscribe-modal-popup .success-message').html(response.message);
                }else{
                    $('.subscribe-modal-popup .success-message').html('');
                    $('.subscribe-modal-popup').modal('openModal');
                    $('.subscribe-modal-popup').addClass('error');                    
                }
                grecaptcha.reset();
            },
        });
    }
});
})
 </script> -->

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                modalClass: 'newsletter-message-pupup',
                title: '<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('')) ?>',
                buttons: [{
                    text: '<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('OK')) ?>',
                    click: function() {
                        this.closeModal();
                        $('.subscribe-modal-popup').removeClass('error');
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('.subscribe-modal-popup'));
        }
    );
</script>
```